# Splitting field for polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

How can I find the splitting field for the polynomial $$x^{p^{50}}-1$$ ??

Could you give me some hints??

To find the splitting field for a polynomial, we have to find all the roots of this polynomial, right?? How could we do this in this case??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up [cyclotomic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). Those are the irreducible factors of polynomials of the form $x^n-1$ in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$. So if you are working over $\Bbb{Q}$ the splitting field will be $F=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)$ with
$\zeta=e^{2\pi i/p^{50}}$. Assuming that $p$ is a prime its degree is $[F:\Bbb{Q}]=\phi(p^{50})=(p-1)p^{49}$.

If you are working over a field other than $\Bbb{Q}$, e.g. one of positive characteristic, then the above degree formula no longer applies.

Comment: To justify that this is the splitting field, do we say that the roots of $x^{p^{50}}-1=0$ are $$1, \zeta, \zeta^2, \dots , \zeta^{p^{50}-1}$$ ?? Could you explain me why the formula for degree stands??

Comment: Yup, those are the roots, so by adjoining $\zeta$ you get the rest of them as well. That Wikipage says that proof for degree formula is a non-trivial fact due to Gauss. I'm sure related material has been covered here, but I really recommend learning this from a book. The fact comes up (in the general version) so often.

Comment: Since $$x^{p^{50}}-1 \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$$ is the splitting field $F=\mathbb{Z}_p(\zeta)$ ??

Comment: Depends. If $\Bbb{Z}_p=\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ then we have
$$x^{p^{50}}-1=(x-1)^{p^{50}}.$$ In other words $x=1$ is the only root, and it has multiplicity $p^{50}$.

Comment: Does this mean that the splitting field is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ ??

Comment: Yes, @Mary. That is correct. If you want to find the splitting field of that polynomial over $\Bbb{Z}_p$ you don't need to adjoin anything!

Comment: I understand!! Thank you very much!! :-)